# Force connection to device over certain network interface in Windows 10

Tags: networking

My PC running Windows 10 has two network interfaces, one wired and one wireless. By default, the PC should communicate to the Internet via the wireless interfaces because it is faster, which I already achieved by modifying the priority of the network interfaces. However, I would like to access my NAS via the wired connection because both the PC and the NAS are connected via the same switch. For some weird reason, sometimes Windows does this automatically, but other times, either right from from the start after it booted *or* after a certain amount of time like an hour, it decides to access the NAS via the wireless connection.

Is it possible to force Windows to access a device (the NAS) via a certain network interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the
[route command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008)
to create a high-priority route to the NAS that uses the right interface.

An example command might be:

```
route add 10.41.1.1 mask 255.255.255.0 10.27.0.1 if 0x3
```

You may find the index of the interface by using the command `route print`.